# Sum of a sequence following a pattern

Tags: sequences-and-series

\begin{gather*}
Let\ a_{1} =1\ \\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a_{2} =1+a_{1}\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a_{3} =1+a_{1} .a_{2}\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a_{4} =1+a_{1} .a_{2} .a_{3}\\
\\
\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a_{n+1} =1+a_{1} .a_{2} .a_{3} ........a_{n}\\
\\
\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ then\ the\ value\ of\ \ \\
\sum ^{\infty }_{r=1}\frac{1}{a_{r}} =
\end{gather*}

Comment: Hi Aman, what have you tried in order to solve your question?

Comment: Do you expect there to be an answer in closed form?  If so, why?  The series converges very fast, so numerical estimation should present no problem.

Comment: The series converges to $2$. See [this](https://oeis.org/A000058) OEIS entry specifically the part - "The greedy Egyptian representation of $1$ is $1 = 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/7 + 1/43 + 1/1807 + \dots$".

Comment: Thanks your approach helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can show via induction that your sequence satisfies $$a_i = a_{i-1}(a_{i-1}-1)+1$$ for all $i$. 
It follows that $$\frac{1}{a_i-1}-\frac{1}{a_{i+1}-1}=\frac{1}{a_i}$$ whenever $i>1$.

Hence $$\sum_{i=1}^{j-1} \frac{1}{a_i} = 1+\sum_{i=2}^{j-1} \frac{1}{a_i}=1+\sum_{i=2}^{j-1} \left( \frac{1}{a_i-1}-\frac{1}{a_{i+1}-1} \right) = 1+\frac{1}{a_2-1} - \frac{1}{s_1-1} = 1+1 - \frac{1}{s_j-1}.$$

It follows that the sum of the reciprocals of $a_i$ converges to $2$.

---

*Remark.* Your sequence is simply [Sylvester's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence) with an added $1$ in the beginning.

Comment: Thanks a lot Maximillian

Comment: @Aman Gupta You're welcome. Please mark my answer as accepted if it answered your question

Comment: Actually I cannot upvote as I am having less than 15 reputations. Thanks again..

Comment: @AmanGupta But you can [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/452068) :)